# Kafka ProducerRecord setting kafka message key to "1"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm facing a weird scenario in a Spring Boot application that uses Kafka and I don't really understand why.

I have a Kafka Producer that sends kafka message that can represent several types of events. Those events are represented by a couple of mandatory fields, `eventType` and `eventKey`. the second field may represent different information from a conceptual point of view depending on the kind of event represented, although it will always be a string.

As the key of the kafka message I am assigning the same value that the `eventKey` field has, so it would be a string as well. However, I have observed that sometimes instead of putting the value that I indicate the key of the message kafka is initialized to "1". This is when the value is a string containing dashes "-".

This is the way I'm generating the Kafka message.

```
public Mono<SendResult<String, GenericJsonMessage>> send(final String eventKey, @Valid final ObjectRest message)
{
    requireNonNull(message, "Message can't be null");

    final GenericJsonMessage jsonMessage = TypedJsonMessage
        .jsonBuilder(ObjectRest.class)
        .build(message).toGenericJsonMessage();

    final ProducerRecord<String, GenericJsonMessage> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, eventKey, jsonMessage);
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get()).subscribeOn(scheduler);
}
```

I'm wondering why this apparent limitation of the `ProducerRecord`  class and I imagine it has to do with the type of characters supported, which produces an error, and then sets the key to 1.

I have never seen this before and have not been able to find an explanation that confirms my suspicions.

I'm not facing really a blocking problem. I already applied a workaround and deleted the hypens. Just curious about it.

Edit:

The assumption of the setting to 1 was wrong. Doing some more research on how it works and how the key of a kafka message is processed internally I found out that it is binarized and that one option is to assign Serializers of string, integer and other data types and then, on the consumer, implement its consequent deserializer.

Now I realize that what was happening was not that it was set to 1 but what kafka does when a string serializer is not assigned is to truncate the key where it finds a non-numeric character (I imagine that by default it must apply aninteger serializer). As my keys started with 1 followed by a - and some numbers the key was truncated after the first character, a 1, and therefore the key remained as 1.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What is `eventKey`? What is calling `send()`? Where are you using to check what the key is? What consumer code do you have?

Comment: @OneCricketeer eventKey as said is a string following the format "1-some numbers". send() is the internal method of KafkaTemplate class in org.springframework.kafka.core package. I still don't have any consumer for that topic. I attached an edit within the question

Comment: [Kafka doesn't default to Integer or String serializer.](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) As I asked, please show more of your code and your Spring config